# How can I resize an NTFS disk image in Windows?

Tags: images

I saved a disk partition to an .IMG file, but it's only 128MB. What tool can I use to resize it to 256MB and keep it still bootable?

Comment: I've only had experience resizing on disk, not 'images' but regardless... **Keep a backup before attempting it!**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Windows tools able to deal with raw filesystem images, so here's a Linux answer. Use any Live CD – [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), Ubuntu, etc.

1. Expand the "partition" by appending 128 MB of any data:

   ```
   $ set -o noclobber

   $ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=128 >> imagefile.img
   ```
2. Expand the inside filesystem:

   ```
   $ sudo -s

   # device=$(losetup -f)
   # losetup $device imagefile.img

   # bytes=$(stat -c %s imagefile.img)
   ```

   ('dd' uses binary megabytes while 'ntfsresize -s' takes decimal ones;
        therefore `-s 256M` would not work as expected and you have to specify
        the size in bytes.)

   ```
   # ntfsresize -s $bytes -n $device
   # ntfsresize -s $bytes $device
   ```

   (The first command, with `-n`, does a test run. The second, *without* `-n`, actually resizes the filesystem.)

   ```
   # losetup -d $device
   ```